# Tab Bar Controller Gray

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5.1.1, Deployment to SDK 7.1. For some reason when I add a Tab Bar Controller, the Items in the bottom does not show up, all bottom bar is gray, the View Controllers associated has the same gray bar, and do not show the items. When I run the simulator the Items Bar is normal. Already tried to change to global tint, re-start Xcode, new project and still the same.
I really appreciate any suggestion.

[image: This is what happens when I add a Tab Bar Controller]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before and after search found it is a bug in Xcode 5. After I reinstall Xcode the problem did not occur anymore.

Comment: Hi there any other suggestion on how to fix this? Is it so difficult?